# How can i make tel and sms as external links in Phonegap with iOS Content-Security-Policy

Tags: ios, cordova, hyperlink, external

I have trouble getting external links to work. With proper CSP am I unable to retrieve data with Ajax. Otherwise, tel, sms, mailto dont work in iOS. Works fine in Android. I can even pay if anyone can help me with this problem. I need to get through school app.

Comment: Please share code of your `index.html`

Comment: I sent you mail, i hope you can help me with this. I will also add the index.html here so maybe we can add solution for this problem so other people can make benefit of this question.